# javascript scripts not working in electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I am trying to work on electron and made a simple dashboard GUI. i am a beginner in node js and electron.

Problem:
in my main gui.html: i have a table is being loaded, and from that table i need to select the rows from checklist for which i have made a js script:

script in read_checklist.js, this is taking the input checkbox element and selecting the whole row, which will later be shown after some processing in the textarea.

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
var select_all = document.getElementById("allcb");
var warn_code = Array();
var family_array = Array();
var fail_drive_array = Array();
var waiverMap = {};
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
          var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
          checkbox.onclick = function() {
              var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
              var Warn_Code = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
              var Family = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
              var failing_drive = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
              
              warn_code.push(Warn_Code.textContent);
              family_array.push(Family.textContent);
              fail_drive_array.push(failing_drive.textContent);
              console.log('server started!' + currentRow  );
              alert(currentRow.textContent);
          };
}
```

I am trying to import this in my gui.html like this:
This is where the table is getting displayed (code for this is below and it is stored in the renderer.js)

```
<!--This is for the table-->
      
    <div id="data_lib" class="table-responsive">
      
    </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="./read_checklist.js"></script>

<!--This is for the table-->
```

My table is coming from another file, renderer.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data;
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",  
      url: "/Users/mrimat01/Desktop/CODE/electron_QAB_GUI_main/GUI/data.csv",
      dataType: "text",       
      success: function(response)  
      {
      data = $.csv.toArrays(response);
      generateHtmlTable(data);
      }   
    });
    function generateHtmlTable(data) {
        var html = "<table  id='big_tables' class='table table-striped table-bordered' method='GET'>";
        
  if(typeof(data[0]) === 'undefined') {
      return null;
      } else {
      $.each(data, function( index, row ) {
      //bind header
      if(index == 0) {
      html += '<thead>';
      html += '<tr>';
      $.each(row, function( index, colData ) {
        html += '<th>';
        html += colData;
        html += '</th>';
      });
        html += '<th>';
        html += "<input type='checkbox' id='allcb' name='allcb'/>Select";
        html += '</th>';

        html += '</tr>';
        html += '</thead>';
        html += '<tbody>';
      } else {
        html += '<tr>';
        $.each(row, function( index, colData ) {
        html += '<td>';
        html += colData;
        html += '</td>';
      });
        html += '<td>';
        html += "<input id='name' type='checkbox' name='name' value='name' />&nbsp;";
        html += '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        }
        });
        html += '</tbody>';
        html += '</table>';
     
      $('#data_lib').append(html);
      }
      }
      
  });
```

I can see the table getting generated but read_checklist.js desn't work.
If i try to do the same thing in console, it works perfectly.

i have gone through many SO answers but couldn't seem to make this work.

Things i have tried:

1. making `node_integration: true`
2. using

   ```
      module = undefined;}</script>

   <script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
   ```
3. adding the script directly below root `<div>`

Comment: Please write read_checklist.js code inside $(document).ready(function(){}): so it will load automatically.

Comment: Yes, this is working. thanks a lot!